# Apple Mach-O linker (ld) error using freenect library

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, mach-o

When trying to compile the following file in xcode:

http://openkinect.org/wiki/C%2B%2BOpenCvExample

I get these errors:

```
Ld build/Debug/KinectOpenCV normal x86_64
cd "/Users/Scott/Dropbox/Project/KinectOpenCV/KinectOpenCV"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk "-L/Users/Scott/Dropbox/Project/KinectOpenCV/KinectOpenCV/build/Debug" "-F/Users/Scott/Dropbox/Project/KinectOpenCV/KinectOpenCV/build/Debug" -filelist "/Users/Scott/Dropbox/Project/KinectOpenCV/KinectOpenCV/build/KinectOpenCV.build/Debug/KinectOpenCV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/KinectOpenCV.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -lopencv_core.2.3.2 -lopencv_highgui.2.3.2 -lfreenect.0.0.1 -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -o "/Users/Scott/Dropbox/Project/KinectOpenCV/KinectOpenCV/build/Debug/KinectOpenCV"

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_freenect_find_video_mode", referenced from:
  freenect_threadfunc(void*) in main.o
"_freenect_set_video_mode", referenced from:
   freenect_threadfunc(void*) in main.o
"_freenect_find_depth_mode", referenced from:
  freenect_threadfunc(void*) in main.o
"_freenect_set_depth_mode", referenced from:
  freenect_threadfunc(void*) in main.o
"_freenect_select_subdevices", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've been trying everything I can think off to resolve the issue but no joy. I've tried compiling for specific architectures (32 bit or 64), I've tried relinking all the libraries and other such measures like starting a new project and importing everything again.

Comment: and do you have the freenect lib installed in your /usr/local/lib, like the makefile on the bottom of that OpenKinect.org web page says?

Comment: Yeah, free freenect lib is installed. I can run glview and the other examples from the command line. I've also got the library imported into xcode

Comment: in Terminal, go to /usr/local/lib and do a `nm` on the freenect library and look through the symbols and let me know if you see `_freenect_find_video_mode`, `_freenect_select_subdevices`, or any of the other symbols from your original list of errors.  If you see them listed in there, then you have a problem with the XCode Project you've created (and we can try to solve that); if you don't see them listed in the library, you need to recompile your freenect lib to include those symbols.

Comment: Those symbols don't appear to be there. How would I go about recompiling the library to include the symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to rebuild libfreenect.

I'd suggest following the [directions on this tutorial](http://www.freenect.com/how-to-get-the-kinect-working-on-mac-os-x) and once you have everything re-installed, run that `nm` test again and see if the symbols finally appear.

If they don't, grep through the library source and see if they are defined and simply conditionalized out for some reason.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" and/or upvote answers that truly help you out on [SO]. You (and everyone else) will be glad you did.

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation to vote you up, I would otherwise. I'm new to StackOverflow at the moment

Comment: Ahh, you're doing good so far.  I hope you'll have a long and fun time here.